# Kendo grid AngularJS - Create a formula builder in kendo ui grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid, formula-editor

I have a kendo ui grid with multiple columns. And I want to create a formula builder(like a pop up) so that user can select multiple columns with some operators(+,-,*,/) and display the result in another column.

Is there any way to do this for Kendo UI grid?

Comment: Like a spreadsheet? [There is a kendo ui widget for creating spreadsheets.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/spreadsheet)

Comment: No, not like a spreadsheet . I want a popup where the user can select columns and operators by their choice and generate a formula and result of that formula can display in another field of the grid. something like we have in infragistics: https://www.infragistics.com/help/aspnet/webcalcmanager-using-formula-builder-to-generate-calculations

Comment: i doubt that is supported right now (unless you create it by customizing the widget)so i think this is like a feature request, you should post on kendo user voice ?